# how to get the list of testRunner properties or methods, enter the .(dot) after instance like testRunner

Tags: groovy, soapui

how can i get the auto list of all properties and methods testRunner supports like java system.(dot)  it gives list of properties it supports

is there any plugin to install?

Comment: Are you using free edition ?

Comment: I've don't know about auto-list, but SmartBear's website does have full documentation about each class.  Here's the link to testRunner - https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/apidocs/soapui/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestRunner.html.  I'd be interested to see what Rao comes up with.

Comment: @ChrisAdams, I don't have any magic :-). SoapUI Pro provide the intellisense in groovy script test step. That's why I was asking if free edition is used? Which does not have that option.

Comment: oh ok thanks Mr.Rao , yes using free edition

Comment: I have the pro licensed version, but running 4.5.0 I think.  I had problems s getting 5 to run.  There’s no intellisense in my version.  What are you running on?

Comment: Correction.  I’m running Pro 5.0.0.